# SQL Parameter out of index error

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting this error when i try to execute this piece of code. When i remove the quotes of the question marks, then it says "You have an error in your SQL syntax;"
Can somebody help me to get this fixed?

```
String query = "select date from ticket where date >='?' and date <= '?'  ";

        PreparedStatement pstmt1 =  con.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt1.setString(1, fromdate);
        pstmt1.setString(2, todate);
        pstmt1.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: You don't quote parameters, just use `where date >= ? and date <= ?`

Comment: I removed quotes and them it says You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: What's the error? Also, have you seen the `BETWEEN` clause, eg `WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?`

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and date <=?' at line 1

Comment: Update your question with the current code. Don't type it, copy and paste

Comment: I tried BETWEEN too but still the same error :-(

Answer (score 2):

Your actual error here is that you're executing the *query string itself* rather than the prepared statement:

```
pstmt1.executeQuery(query);
```

There is no `executeQuery(String)` in the `PreparedStatement` interface, instead it reverts to the one from the `Statement` interface, which just runs the string, as-is, as a query. That means it will complain bitterly because `?` is not considered valid in that context.

You *should* just be using (including retrieving the result set):

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt1.executeQuery();
```

so the query execution is done in the prepared statement context rather than the statement context.

Comment: `date` is a valid column name that doesn't need identifier quotes. See the list under this table - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-new-5.5

Answer (score 0):

Do not enclose the placeholders with quotes

```
String query = "select date from ticket where date >='?' and date <= '?'  ";
```

The java API will take care of adding quotes and adding escape sequences to the special characters, this should suffice:

```
String query = "select date from ticket where date >=? and date <= ?  ";
```

Answer (score 0):

setString(...) --> setDate(...)